# C++ Constructor setting all values to zero

Tags: c++

```
struct AnimationData
{
    struct Frame
    {
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        float dt; // seconds
        Frame() : x1(0), y1(0), x2(1), y2(1), dt(1) {}
    } * frames;

    int frame_count;

    std::string name;

    AnimationData(int fc, std::string n) : frame_count(fc), name(n)
    {
        frames = new Frame[fc];
        for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++)
        {
            std::cout << frames[i].x2 << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main()
{

    AnimationData data{10, "test"};
    data.frames[1].x1 = 666;

    std::cout << "Start" << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < data.frame_count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << data.frames[i].x1 << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
Start
0
666
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why Does it turn everything to zero except for the one I set? (Note I know nothing about copy and move constructors idk if they are related to this)

Comment: This question really could use more text explaining the situation. Please see [ask] and try to explain what your code does in words, along with why you expected something different, before asking us to read through poorly-formatted code.

Comment: All of them are initially `0` per the member initialization you did at the default-ctor. You only changed one afterward (and it shows).

Comment: I recommend changing this to `struct Frame { int x1{0}, y1{0}, x2{1}, y2{1}; float dt{1}; /* seconds */ } * frames;` The benefit of this syntax is that if you (later) write a constructor `Frame(int x1_, int x2_) : x1(x1_), x2(x2_) { }` the remaining member variables still get initialized. Plus it's less to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Does it turn everything to zero except for the one I set?

Because the default constructor `Frame::Frame()` will initialize `x1`, `y1` to `0` and `x2`, `y2`, `dt` to `1` when you wrote:

```
frames = new Frame[fc]; //default ctor will initialize x1, y1 to 0 and x2, y2, dt to 1
```

That is, the `10` `Frame` objects that will be allocated on the heap will be created using the **default constructor** of `Frame` which will initialize `x1`, `y1` to `0` and `x2`, `y2` and `dt` to `1`. This is why when you wrote:

```
std::cout << frames[i].x2 << '\n'; //prints 1 becasue default ctor initialized `x2` to `1`
```

the above statement will print `1` as default ctor initialized `x2` to `1`

For the same reason when you wrote:

```
std::cout << data.frames[i].x1 << '\n'; //will print 0 as default ctro initialized x1 to 0 except for `data.frames[1].x1` which you set to `666`.
```

the above statement will print `0` since the default ctor initialized `x1` to `0` except for `data.frames[1].x1` which you specifically set to `666`.

You can confirm that the default ctor is used by adding a cout statement inside it as done below:

```
Frame() : x1(0), y1(0), x2(1), y2(1), dt(1) {
        std::cout<<"default ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
```

The [output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/crpct7IekzgHxhBf) of the modified program is:

```
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
default ctor called
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
Start
0
666
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```